# ¿Cómo ejecutar primero el Controller antes que la directiva Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Me podrían ayudar en dar un ejemplo o documentación de como renderizar primero todo el controller antes que se ejecute una directiva customizada.

Lo que tengo en el controller es un valor: `$scope.total = 200;`

En el HTML tengo lo siguiente

```
<div val-Custom><ul><li data-value="{{total}}"></li></ul></div>
```

Ahora quiero atrapar ese valor en mi directiva ejem:

```
ctrlsaldosyconsumos.directive('valCustom', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    //aqui hago otras cosas me interesa mas 
    attrs.$observe('valCustom', function() {
         element.find('li').animate({ width: element.attr("data-value") + '%' }, 350);
    });
}
})
```

Ahora ese data-value en la directiva me sale `undefined` y si lo pongo, por ejemplo

```
<li data-value="200"></li>
```

Esto sí se ejecuta correctamente. Pienso que primero se está ejecutando la directiva sin haber cargado el valor del controlador (`$scope.total`).

Alguna sugerencia o ayuda les agradeceré, estoy iniciando en esto de AngularJS (Angular 1) y más en directivas. Gracias .

Comment: El ajax lo ejecutas en el mismo controlador?

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta corta:

**Siempre se ejecuta primero el controller antes que la directiva**

Respuesta larga:

Primero que nada recuerda que `ng-controller` es una directiva también. El orden de ejecución de las directivas es el siguiente

```
compile padre
compile hijo
controller padre  =>  ng-controller
pre-link padre
controller hijo   =>  tu directiva
pre-link hijo
post-link hijo
post-link padre
```

Lo puedes comprobar en el siguiente snippet

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('padre', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function() {
        console.log('Compile padre');
        return {
          pre: function() {
            console.log('Pre padre');
          },
          post: function() {
            console.log('Post padre');
          }
        };
      },
      controller: function() {
        console.log('Controller padre');
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('hijo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function() {
        console.log('Compile hijo');
        return {
          pre: function() {
            console.log('Pre hijo');
          },
          post: function() {
            console.log('Post hijo');
          }
        };
      },
      controller: function() {
        console.log('Controller hijo');
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <padre>
    <hijo></hijo>
  </padre>
</div>
```

Lo que significa que si tu directiva está en el DOM dentro de tu controller **nunca** se ejecutará primero que este.

Si tu código depende de llamadas Ajax, da igual en el orden que lo ejecutes, es probable que tu directiva llegue a la fase `post-link` y aún no hayan llegado los resultados vía ajax.

La solución podría ser usar `ng-if` para señalizar cuando se puede renderizar la directiva.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('UtilCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.muestraHijo = false;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.muestraHijo = true;
    }, 1000)
  })
  .directive('padre', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function() {
        console.log('Compile padre');
        return {
          pre: function() {
            console.log('Pre padre');
          },
          post: function() {
            console.log('Post padre');
          }
        };
      },
      controller: function() {
        console.log('Controller padre');
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('hijo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function() {
        console.log('Compile hijo');
        return {
          pre: function() {
            console.log('Pre hijo');
          },
          post: function() {
            console.log('Post hijo');
          }
        };
      },
      controller: function() {
        console.log('Controller hijo');
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="UtilCtrl">
  <padre>
    <div ng-if="muestraHijo">
      <hijo></hijo>
    </div>
  </padre>
</div>
```

Lee https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives

> Si necesitas esperar a que los datos del `$scope` hayan terminado de cargar intenta usando `ng-if` para retrasar el procesado de un bloque de DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te pueda orientar, yo lo soluciones de esta manera:

```
<div val-Custom algo="$scope.algo">
    <ul>
        <li data-value="{{total}}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

En tu directiva indicale lo siguiente:

```
ctrlsaldosyconsumos.directive('valCustom', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        algo: '=algo'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        console.log("llamando al scope.algo deberias tener disponible tus datos")
        attrs.$observe('valCustom', function() {
            element.find('li').animate({ width: element.attr("data-value") + '%' }, 350);
        });
      }
    }
})
```

Esto te podria ayudar a comprender el funcionamiento:

[Documentario AngularJS (Angular 1)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Navega al partado que dice: **Isolating the Scope of a Directive**

Saludos, espero ayudarte o guiarte.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el valor `$scope.total` lo obtengo de una llamada ajax por lo que cuando renderiza el DOM al parecer lo ejecuta tan rapido que no carga los datos del controller. no se que puedo hacer ?

Answer (score 0):

Problema semejante, lo solucioné considerando $watch dentro del controlador de mi directiva, en este caso era un atributo de tipo colección:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("datos", function (newValue, oldValue) {            
    if (newValue === oldValue) {
        return;
    }
    if ($scope.datos != undefined)
        loadGraphEChart($scope.labels, $scope.datos, $scope.titulo, $scope.idgraph);
});
```

con lo anterior, logré que la loadGraphEChart se ejecutara una vez que

```
$scope.datos != undefined
```

NOTA: el valor de datos no se asignaba dado algún evento del usuario, sino que se alimentaba como un atributo de la directiva dada la respuesta a una solicitud http

```
<div echart-graph ng-model="edades"
                                                     idgraph="Edades"
                                                     stilo="height:350px;width:98%;"
                                                     titulo="Edades"
                                                     labels="edades.labels"
                                                     datos="edades.datos"></div>
```